# In Python How Come this IF statement doesn't work but this ELIF does.

Tags: python, if-statement

Everything works with this one:

```
    if propRiskElem.text == 'High Risk Zone A':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone A</CLR>"""
    elif propRiskElem.text == 'High Risk Zone AE':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone AE</CLR>"""
    elif propRiskElem.text == 'Low Risk':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "0" green = "128" blue = "0">Low Risk</CLR>"""
    else:
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "165" blue = "0">Moderate Risk</CLR>""" 

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

But for this version, everything in the first two ifs gets pushed down to the else:

```
    if propRiskElem.text == 'High Risk Zone A':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone A</CLR>"""
    if propRiskElem.text == 'High Risk Zone AE':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone AE</CLR>"""
    if propRiskElem.text == 'Low Risk':
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "0" green = "128" blue = "0">Low Risk</CLR>"""
    else:
        propRiskElem.text = """<CLR red = "255" green = "165" blue = "0">Moderate Risk</CLR>""" 

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Sort of irritating to me, but at least the first one works.  I'm trying to understand why sometimes I need to use elif and sometimes I don't.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's what the code in the second block says to do. Consider the last `if/else`: If that if fails, the else is taken, which it will do even if the first or second if was already taken.

Comment: in your second version, last `else` statement won't be executed if (and only) the last `if` is True, in every other case, it will be executed.

Comment: Better to use a `dict.get()` with a default.

Comment: @Blusky string objects do not have an `.equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code block, the `else` will always be triggered if (and only if) `propRiskElem.text == 'Low Risk'` is `False`, that's why.

On your first block, the `else` will be triggered if all your `if` and `elif` are `False`

Answer (score 0):

In your second example (without elif) all the 3 if conditions will be checked all the time, and the else is associated ONLY with the last if.
If any of the first 2 check matches, the 3rd if will definitely fail and IT'S else action will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code will obviously not work because

> if:
>
> 'do-something'
>
> if:
>
> 'do-something'
>
> if:
>
> 'do-something'
>
> else:
>
> 'do something else'

Observe here , if your if statement is false it doesn't even get into the next set of if statements it just directly hits the else statements.

On the other hand

> if:
>
> ```
> 'do-something'
> ```
>
> elif:
>
> ```
> 'do-something'
> ```
>
> else:
>
> ```
> 'do something else'
> ```

Here if your if goes wrong it will next check for if-else and try to check if it has to validate that, if even thats wrong it will then go to else finally.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary like this:

```
risks = {'High Risk Zone A': """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone A</CLR>""",
    'High Risk Zone AE': """<CLR red = "255" green = "0" blue = "0">High Risk Zone AE</CLR>""",
    'Low Risk': """<CLR red = "0" green = "128" blue = "0">Low Risk</CLR>""" }
```

This functions reads from the `dict`

```
def transform_text(text):
    return risks.get(text,"""<CLR red = "255" green = "165" blue = "0">Moderate Risk</CLR>""")
```

Call the function like this:

```
propRiskElem.text = transform_text(propRiskElem.text)
```